# aws cli fails to return a role policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I am copying the name of a policy a created (and attached to a role) and running the following command:

```
▶ aws iam get-role-policy --role-name MyRole  --policy-name MyPolicy
```

however I am getting:

```
An error occurred (NoSuchEntity) when calling the GetRolePolicy operation: The role policy with name MyPolicy cannot be found.
```

The policy is right there, I am copying the name from the AWS console.

What is the issue here?

I have also tried the following, that does list the policy

```
$ aws iam list-attached-role-policies --role-name MyRole

{
    "AttachedPolicies": [
        {
            "PolicyName": "MyPolicy",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:policy/MyPolicy"
        }
    ]
}
(END)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`list-attached-role-policies`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/iam/list-attached-role-policies.html) lists all *managed* policies attached to a role and [`get-role-policy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-role-policy.html) retrieves an *inline* policy. In order to retrieve a managed policy you'll want to use [`get-policy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-policy.html), get the policy version from there and retrieve it using [`get-policy-version`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-policy-version.html).